# NullpointerException not showing file name and line number

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a problem, my activity closes while `switching` between the tabs, i have 2 tabs and am using 2 seperate fragments for that.

**This is the error stack**

```
06-28 20:32:18.008 10728-10728/com.mycom.myapp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
    06-28 20:32:18.009 10728-10728/com.mycom.myapp W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.getHostVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:1786)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleAppVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:1422)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4804)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    06-28 20:32:18.009 10728-10728/com.mycom.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058)
    06-28 20:32:18.009 10728-10728/com.mycom.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

**Activity Code**

```
public class DummyLsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.pager)
    ViewPager pager;
    @BindView(R.id.tablayout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    private static DummyLsActivity dummyLsActivity = null;
    LockScreenPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy_ls);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("FirstTab"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("SecondTab"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        myPagerAdapter = new LockScreenPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    }

    public static DummyLsActivity getInstance() {
        return dummyLsActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment Code**

```
public class LsFirstFragment extends Fragment {

    Unbinder unbinder;
    View view;
    LsArticlesSharedPreference lsArticlesSharedPreference;

    @BindView(R.id.ls_first_iv)
    ImageView lsFirstIv;
    @BindView(R.id.ls_first_article_head_overlay_tv)
    TextView lsFirstArticleHeadOverlayTv;
    @BindView(R.id.ls_first_swipe_left_tv)
    TextView lsFirstSwipeLeftTv;

    public LsFirstFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ls_first, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        lsArticlesSharedPreference = new LsArticlesSharedPreference();
        loadOfflineArticlesData();
        return view;
    }

    public void loadOfflineArticlesData() {
        if (getContext() != null && lsArticlesSharedPreference != null) {
            List<Articles> savedArticles = lsArticlesSharedPreference.getOfflineDataLs(getContext());
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            if (getActivity() != null && savedArticles != null) {
                lsFirstSwipeLeftTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lsFirstArticleHeadOverlayTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                        .load(savedArticles.get(0).getArticleSecondImage())
                        .thumbnail(Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.logo_anim_full))
                        .into(lsFirstIv);
                lsFirstIv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                lsFirstArticleHeadOverlayTv.setText(savedArticles.get(0).getArticleHeading());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


}
```

**SecondFragment Code**

public class LsSecondFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPagerListener {

```
    View view;
    Unbinder unbinder;

    private LsArticlesAdapter lsArticlesAdapter;
    LsArticlesSharedPreference lsArticlesSharedPreference;
    @BindView(R.id.ls_articles_viewpager)
    ViewPager lsArticlesViewpager;

    public LsSecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ls_second, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        lsArticlesSharedPreference = new LsArticlesSharedPreference();
        loadOfflineArticlesData();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPager(int position) {
        lsArticlesViewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    public void loadOfflineArticlesData() {
        if (getContext() != null && lsArticlesSharedPreference != null) {
            List<Articles> savedArticles = lsArticlesSharedPreference.getOfflineDataLs(getContext());
            if (savedArticles != null && savedArticles.size() == 0) {
                loadOfflineArticlesData();
            } else {
                System.out.println("STORY IS CALLED FIRST");
                lsArticlesAdapter = new LsArticlesAdapter(getContext(), savedArticles);
                lsArticlesViewpager.setAdapter(lsArticlesAdapter);
                lsArticlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

It's showing `Attempt to call virtual method`getVisibility()`on a`null`object reference`, but the fact is, i am not using `getVisibility()` anywhere in the entire project. Can someone point the reason for the same.

Comment: please share  the code

Comment: Hard to tell without the code. Post the part of the code where you think that happens. Like which activity or fragment you opened when this was thrown.

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez posting the code in a while

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz i have an activity and inside that activity i have a tablayout with 2 tabs and 2 fragments, this exception is thrown when switching between the tabs, this is not happening every time, but this is quite frequent

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz, i have updated the code

Comment: `public static DummyLsActivity getInstance()` is not good. If you want to call one of this activity's method from its child fragment, use `((DummyLsActivity) getActivity()).method()`.

Comment: @Mehmed thanks for pointing out, btw could you identify what i am doing wrong here? Or when app throws this exception?